# Visual Community 2022 MFC C++ Project database getting messed up

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

As title says i have a visual community MFC C++ project that seems to be getting messed up.
Inasmuch a when you create a new method using class wizard and add code to the new method then try to find the method using class wizard it goes to the wrong place in the code.
Been long time since i used VS last one was VS 2005 and similar thing used to happen in it prior to project complete meltdown then rewrite. Is there a fix in vs2022 or VS forum place to ask please?
many thanks imk

Comment: The class wizard has been broken for at last 10 years or so. MS did various bug corrections and for simple cases it happens to work most of the time now.

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me, any ideas please?

Comment: There was no MFC Class Wizard in Visual Studio 2005. Did you install some sort of extension that could be responsible for breaking compatibility with Visual Studio?

Comment: I think it was 2005 VS, been long time since I used it.
And from what i can remember there was a code generator function similar to class wizard that used to sometimes mess up a project soo bad that had had to start a new one.. I just witness another significant bug/feature in VS 2022 where I opened the dialog editor and just got a page full of error messages.  Closed project and opened it again and it was ok. Think i may abandon this project and start a new one as it is somehow damaged and maybe BIG issue when i make future edits to it.

Comment: My observation: If you use derived controls, then the mfc class wizard goes soon overwhelmed.

Comment: If you don't spend any time diagnosing what went wrong, you'll indefinitely restart-from-scratch. Experienced MFC developers (or Windows developers, really) have long stopped relying on Visual Studio's tooling. The tooling doesn't offer anything you wouldn't be able to do in code. You might want to consider actually learning MFC rather than dumping time into restarting a new project from scratch. That's time well spent.

Comment: IInspectable
Thanks for the remap view port it has really helped.
As for learning MFC I really only us it every few years for none commercial applications so lot of time to invest learning something might not us again. I have tried to research this issue project messing up issue but the more MS fixes i apply the worse it gets. Must say I normal code manually but though the class wizard as was the way MS wanted me to go and I have be proved wrong. Back to manual coding and hope this project DB is not going to be an issue in the future. Many thanks again for help imk

Comment: @IInspectable There was a ClassWizard. I have never been without one since Visual Studio 6. But it is buggy indeed!